# C++ How to increment value for a key in a map pointer?

Tags: c++, increment, stdmap

I have a map pointer

```
std::map<long, double> *m_map
```

How to Increment the value of a specific key in the  map??
I was using-

```
std::map<long, double> m_map
```

I used it without pointer, which i could increment by-

```
map['a']++.
```

I have to do the same incremental in a pointer map. Help me in this regard.

Comment: Your question actually is "How do you de-reference a pointer in C++". I think that may already be covered somewhere.

Comment: You can go from pointer to object with `*`. Since `[]` have higher precedence that `*`, you need parentheses: `(*m_map)['a']++`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method `at`:

```
m_map->at('a')++;
```

Comment: That's not really the same, `at` throws when the key isn't found, `operator[]` creates the entry in that case